# Microsoft word - custom field with section specific data

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2007

I am using Word 2007 on Windows XP (unable to change this).

I am creating a page template and want to show a specific piece of information in the header of each page that is section specific. It should be the same on each page belonging to each section and user editable (with preferably a default placeholder).

E.g.,

In section 1 that spans pages 1-5 the value may be `KSF 100`, in section 2 that spans pages 6-9 the value may be `KSF 200`. On pages 1-5 I want to display `KSF 100` in the header and on pages 6-9 I want to display `KSF 200`.

How would I go about implementing this?

Comment: Are you asking for a page header/footer? How would you decide what gets written on each page? Where would the default placeholder get its text from?

Comment: @CanadianLuke It will go in the header but that's not important. That's my question... the input would be manual by whoever is writing the document however I don't want to specify it on every page but by section.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have per-section (unlinked) headers then in one sense, all you need is an area with a placeholder text that the user can replace. Traditionally, one way to do that is to use a { MACROBUTTON } field as a placeholder, like this

```
{ MACROBUTTON Nomacro The placeholder text }
```

(Where Nomacro is a non-existent macro name, anf the {} is a special field code brace pair that you can insert using ctrl-F9 on Windows Word)

When the user type in that field, the field and its placeholder text are removed.

That works in headers as well as in the body of the document. The main drawback is, I suppose, that if the user deletes their text, the placeholder does not reappear. But I suspect other simple things the user could do (such as add or delete section breaks) might be more likely to break the document, whichever method you used.

If you want a single header (i.e. all headers are linked to the Section 1 header), then the traditional way to get per-section text in a header is to use a { STYLEREF } field that references a paragraph or text area with a specific style, typically at or near the beginning of each section.

Most other things seem more complex and probably less robust than is likely to be worth it. For example, you could insert the value of a Document Variable or Custom Document Property for each section using a nested field such as

```
{ DOCVARIABLE "header{ SECTION }" }
```

but there would be no in-situ edits, and you would have to use VBA to provide a mechanism for the user to modify the document variables. Using Custom Document Properties, you could pre-populate a certain number and use

```
{ DOCPROPERTY "header{ SECTION }" }
```

and tell the user how to use the existing property editor, but that isn't straightforward.

Finally, if the section count is fixed and you can use unlinked headers, you could use content controls linked to a custom XML data store. These have proper placeholders and are editable in situ, but again there is the question of how you sort out a document that has had sections added/removed. Below is a code example to do the initial set up of a blank document with a specified number of sections and a content control in each header. This would only work on Windows Word 2007 and later.

```
Sub makeMappedCCPerSection()
' Run this with a newly created document
' Set this to the number of sections you want
Const sectioncount As Integer = 5
Dim cc As Word.ContentControl
Dim cxp As Office.CustomXMLPart
Dim cxpXML As String
Dim i As Integer
' the number of sections in your document
'Dim sectioncount As Integer

cxpXML = ""
cxpXML = cxpXML & "<root xmlns:hcc='header content control'>" & vbCrLf
cxpXML = cxpXML & "<sections>" & vbCrLf
For i = 1 To sectioncount
  cxpXML = cxpXML & "<section/>" & vbCrLf
Next
cxpXML = cxpXML & "</sections>" & vbCrLf
cxpXML = cxpXML & "</root>" & vbCrLf

With ActiveDocument
  For i = .CustomXMLParts.Count To 1 Step -1
    With .CustomXMLParts(i)
      If Not .BuiltIn Then
        .Delete
      End If
    End With
  Next
  Set cxp = .CustomXMLParts.Add(cxpXML)
  For i = 1 To sectioncount - 1
    .Content.InsertBreak WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage
  Next
  For i = sectioncount To 1 Step -1
    .Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text = " "
    If i > 1 Then
      .Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
    End If
    Set cc = .Sections(i).Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.ContentControls.Add(wdContentControlText)
    cc.SetPlaceholderText Text:="Section " & CStr(i) & " placeholder"
    cc.XMLMapping.SetMapping "/root/sections/section[" & CStr(i) & "]", , cxp
    Set cxp = Nothing
    Set cc = Nothing
  Next
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: This is a fantastic answer and I will probably use the `{STYLEREF}` as the whole point is to allow the reader to know which section they are in when it spans many pages (This is a long boring table, with many codenamed sections). Thank you

Comment: Sensible choice, IMO!

Answer (score 0):

One other suggestion to complement bibadia's answer. If you were in a situation when you didn't want the input text to be visible inside the document all the time you could instead insert a content control in each section and make the control hidden (you could also enforce that the control cannot be deleted for integrity). Wrap the entire content control in a bookmark and in your footer add a REF field which points to the bookmark and will pick up whatever text has been entered by the user.

You can then instruct your user to turn on non printing symbols to see the content control whenever they wish to update the header footer and turn it off to hide the input. Note that STYLEREF will not pick up hidden text.